# Strcmp function and char arrays

Tags: c, c-strings, strcmp

The strcmp function in c is showing some weird behavior.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
   char inst1[] = {'A'};
   char inst2[] = {'A'};    
   printf("%d\n",strcmp(inst1, inst2));

   return 0;
}
```

The above code produces an output 65, but it should have produced 0 from my understanding.
Even more weird behavior follows when I run a slightly different code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
   char inst1[] = {'A'};
   char inst2[] = {'A'};
    
   char inst3[] = {'B'};
   char inst4[] = {'B'};

   printf("%d\n",strcmp(inst1, inst2));
   printf("%d\n",strcmp(inst3, inst4));

   return 0;
}
```

The above code produces an output-

```
-1
66
```

I have no idea why strcmp is producing such outputs.

Comment: It's easy. You called `strcmp()`. So think 'string compare'. But those are not strings. They are arrays of `char`. Big diff!

Answer (score 4):

Your arrays are not null-terminated, so passing them to `strcmp()` is not allowed because `strcmp()` expects strings (null-terminated sequence of characters) and passing non-null-terminated arrays will lead to out-of-range access looking for terminating null-character.

You should add terminating null-character like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
   char inst1[] = {'A', '\0'};
   char inst2[] = {'A', '\0'};    
   printf("%d\n",strcmp(inst1, inst2));

   return 0;
}
```

Or easier version:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
   char inst1[] = "A";
   char inst2[] = "A";    
   printf("%d\n",strcmp(inst1, inst2));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's another way, that is using `strncmp` with no need to terminate the array with `\0`

Answer (score 0):

The function `strcmp` is designed to compare strings that is sequences of characters terminated by the zero-terminating character `'\0'`.

However these declarations

```
char inst1[] = {'A'};
char inst2[] = {'A'};
```

do not initialize the character arrays with strings.

So using the function `strcmp` with character arrays that do not store strings invokes undefined behavior.

You should write at least

```
char inst1[] = { "A" };
char inst2[] = { "A" };
```

that is to initialize the arrays with string literals.

Pay attention to that for example the string literal `"A"` is internally stored as a character array with two elements `{ 'A', '\0' }` and the both elements are used to initialize character arrays that have enough space.

Thus for these declarations

```
char inst1[] = {'A'};
char inst2[] = {'A'};
```

`sizeof( inst1 )` and `sizeof( inst2 )` are equal to `1` while for these declarations

```
char inst1[] = { "A" };
char inst2[] = { "A" };
```

`sizeof( inst1 )` and `sizeof( inst2 )` are equal to `2`

For these declarations

```
char inst1[] = {'A'};
char inst2[] = {'A'};
```

you should use the function `memcmp` instead of `strcmp` that is designed to compare sequences of bytes like

```
printf( "%d\n", memcmp(inst1, inst2, sizeof( inst1 ) );
```

You could also use the function `strncmp` but for arrays that do not contain strings using the function is less efficient than using the function `memcmp`.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) 
{
    {
        char inst1[] = { 'A' };
        char inst2[] = { 'A' };    
        
        printf( "%d\n", memcmp( inst1, inst2, sizeof( inst1 ) ) );
    }

    {
        char inst1[] = { "A" };
        char inst2[] = { "A" };    
        
        printf( "%d\n", strcmp( inst1, inst2 ) );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0
0
```